# BaseX: import xar file directly in .xqy file

Tags: xquery, basex

I need to use some external module in BaseX. I install the package first with:

```
$ basex -c"REPO INSTALL http://files.basex.org/modules/expath/functx-1.0.xar"
```

So I wonder if there is a way not to install this package with the command above, but reference the module in .xqy like:

```
import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com" at "functx-1.0.xar";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. However, you can either specify your query as second argument after the REPO COMMAND call (in the same BaseX call) and drop it afterwards, similar to:

```
basex -c"REPO INSTALL http://files.basex.org/modules/expath/functx-1.0.xar"
    your-query.xq -c"REPO DELETE functx-1.0.xar"
```

Or you’ll need to unzip the XAR file in advance and reference with the single functx library module file:

```
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com"
  at "./relative/or/absolute/path/to/functx.xq";
```